# Not able to start TomEE windows service

Tags: windows, tomee-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfok7.jpg)Here I was trying to install TomEE 8.0.9 on my Windows server as a prerequisite for other applications. For that I have installed tomee on my server and it is starting with the startup.bat file. but when I installed Tomee service and tried to start the service as a Windows service getting the below error.

already set permissions for the installation directory and set Catalina home and all other necessary variables.

in log file, i can see some errors like

`< [2023-06-06 13:00:38] [info]  [13220] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.2.2.0 64-bit) started.`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [info]  [13220] Running Service 'TomEE'...`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [info]  [14780] Starting service...`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [error] [15260] CreateJavaVM Failed with error [-6]`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [error] [15260] The system cannot find the file specified.`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [error] [14780] Failed to start Java`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [error] [14780] ServiceStart returned 4.`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [info]  [13220] Run service finished.`

`[2023-06-06 13:00:39] [info]  [13220] Apache Commons Daemon procrun finished.`

Can anybody help me to resolve the issue?